# Disable banners/dot when Do Not Disturb is ON 20.04

Tags: 20.04, notification-area

Want to disable the banners from showing up on apps when I toggle do not disturb. I don't want to do it just for slack, I want to do it for all the apps that have a banner on the top right.
Not sure if this is called badge or dot, but here is example

[image]

I'm ok if the solution hides the entire app icon, just am tired of seeing this badge icon show up when I'm trying to focus on something.

Also, I know there are solutions such as closing the apps and disabling the icon on the top with hide icon, but I am lazy and love one click solutions. Wondering if there is a functionality of Do Not Disturb that would do that.

Noticed Ubuntu AppIndicator can turn off all of those icons... wondering if there could be some trigger on DND to toggle that.

Comment: While not quite what you ask for, there is a GNOME extension which hides the entire top bar. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/. - another option would be to 'full screen' whatever application you're running, so as to obscure the entire bar.

Comment: thanks I'll try that out for now. Although to anyone reading this, I'm still hopeful for another solution